# Interpretation of Training, Testing (Dev) and Validation Score in Machine Learning

Tags: python, validation, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have trained a Machine Learnig Model using Sklearn and looked at different scores for the traing, testing (dev) and validation set.

**Here are the scores**:

`Accuracy on Train: 94.5468% 
Accuracy on Test: 74.4646% 
Accuracy on Validation: 65.6548% 
Precision on Train: 96.7002% 
Precision on Test: 85.2289% 
Precision on Validation: 79.7178% 
F1-Score on Train: 96.9761% 
F1-Score on Test: 85.6203% 
F1-Score on Validation: 79.6747%`

I am having some problems with Interpretation of the scores. Is it normal, that the Model has a much worse result on the validation set?

Do you have thoughts on those results?

Comment: Usually the case is that Validation scores should be better than the Test scores. can you specify what are these scores for (which algorithm or model in Sklearn did you use)?

Comment: I used the RandomForest Classifer. The Validation set is in this case data, which the Model has never seen before.

Comment: There is sometimes a confusing about Test set and Validation set, just to make sure we're on the same page: Validation set is used to tune your classifiers parameters, so model (in a way) has seen it. The Test set is used to find the actual accuracy of model and so the model has never seen it before. Is that what you meant by Validation and Test set?

Comment: Actually i mixed up the terms, in this case validation set = test set and test set = validation set. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: no problem, I posted an answer to your question, don't forget to mark it as correct answer if it answers your question. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained in the comments, your test set is the set you used to tune your parameters and the validation set is the set that your model didn't use for training.

Considering that, it's natural that your Validation scores are lower than other scores.

When you're training a machine learning model, you show the **training set** to your model, that's why your model get's the best scores on training set, i.e. samples it has already seen and knows the answer for.

You use **validation** set to tune your parameters (e.g. degree of complexity in regression and so on) so your parameters are fine tuned for your validation sets but your model has not been trained on them. (for this you used the term test set, and to be fair they are sometimes used that way)

finally you have the least score on your **test set** which is natural since the parameters are not exactly tuned for the test set and the model has never seen them before.

if there is a huge hap between your training and test results, your model might have become overfit and there are ways to avoid that.


hope this helped ;)